# Get timebased UUID from datetime on the jvm

Tags: cassandra, jvm, timeuuid

Cassandra has a timeuuid type, and there are functions to create a timeuuid for "now". There's also documented ways of getting back the time from a timeuuid. However, is there a way to get a timeuuid from a joda DateTime? It feels like this should exist.

Comment: check my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/40459854/2320144

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [UUIDGen class](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/trunk/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/utils/UUIDGen.java#L85-L88). It looks like you could use the following to generate a UUID from a DateTime (using the [getMillis()](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/base/BaseDateTime.html#getMillis--) method).

```
DateTime someDateTime = ...;
UUID timeUUID = UUIDGen.getTimeUUID(someDateTime.getMillis());
```

Comment: That seems to be part of Cassandra itself, rather than in the client library.

Comment: If you prefer client based code there is a [UUIDs](https://github.com/datastax/java-driver/blob/3.x/driver-core/src/main/java/com/datastax/driver/core/utils/UUIDs.java#L229-L275) class as part of the java driver. See [UUIDs.startOf()](http://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java-dse/1.1/com/datastax/driver/core/utils/UUIDs.html#startOf-long-) and [UUIDs.endOf()](http://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java-dse/1.1/com/datastax/driver/core/utils/UUIDs.html#endOf-long-). Convert the Joda DateTime to milliseconds.